# Select time intervals MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table with a date field of "date" type, so in the yyyy-mm-dd format.
I have to query this table to fetch the rows included in a certain time interval (ex. all the rows from
2014-02-04 to 2014-04-04)
Is there a simple way to do this in MySQL or it must be done from php code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `BETWEEN` clause.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN date1 AND date2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2014-02-04' AND '2014-04-04'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE `date` >= '2014-02-04' AND `date`<='2014-04-04'
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20e94/2)